# how to split gulp tasks into multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, babeljs

I have a `gulp` folder with this `gulpfile.js`

```
const source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
const gulp = require('gulp');

module.exports = function(args) {
  gulp.task('default', function() {});
}
```

I have a `project` folder with this `gulpfile.js`

```
const projectGulp = require('../gulp/gulpfile.js')

projectGulp();
```

Inside the `project` folder I have a `package.json` with `vinyl-source-stream` added as dev dependency, now I run `yarn install` on this folder.

When I run `gulp` I get `Cannot find module vinyl-source-stream` error.

If i do to `gulp` folder and do `yarn install vinyl-source-stream` it works fine. Now I get `Task default is not in your gulpfile` error.

Comment: what is your `NODE_ENV` value?

Comment: I don't have that.

Comment: try `yarn install --production=false`

Comment: no it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing the following:

```
  $ yarn install --check-files
```

The `--check-files` flag validates whether packages were not been removed from node_modules folder. (see [yarn documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/install/#toc-yarn-install-check-files)).

In case it won't work, you should try:

```
  $ rm -rf ./node_modules/
  $ npm cache clean
  $ npm install
```

Then probably see if the `vinyl-source-stream` is where it should be:

```
  $ ls ./node_modules/vinyl-source-stream
```

As I'm working mostly on Windows I encountered every possible yarn bug. I used to have similar issues to [this](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2240) and that were the cases when simply removing everything and calling npm helped. Yarn sometimes cannot figure out that dependencies are missing especially with gulp.